# Excel 2016 Pivot Table - Change Data Source Not Updating Correctly

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have been using Excel 2007 for the longest time and was just upgraded to Excel 2016. When trying to update files with Pivot tables that I have used before, I have noticed problems with updating/changing the source data for these pivot tables.

As a simple example, I create a new worksheet in a new workbook and name the sheet "January". I can enter January sale data, and create a Pivot Table based on the data, by selecting the data range. If I copy that January sheet and create a new sheet and name it February, I want to be able to change the data source to the data on the new sheet. When I go in to change the data source and edit it from January to February, it lets me type it in but when I close, it does not pull in the February data. If I go back in, it still says January.

I know in excel 2007, I was able to do it this way and it would work.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue also, did you find a fix?

Comment: See below thread https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_o365b/excel-2016-pivot-tables/a2f13ded-3957-436d-a47c-153382c870c3?auth=1

Comment: Thanks, I'd already come to the conclusion that specifying a different row range worked around this issue. Cheers.